Indecomposability of Lie groups and their associated Lie algebra
I am working with Lie groups and I stumbled upon a problem.
Let $G$ be a connected Lie group with associated Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$. Assume that $\mathfrak g$ has a decomposition as a direct sum of non-trivial ideals
$$ \mathfrak g = \mathfrak g_1 \oplus \mathfrak g_2.$$
I know that there exist unique connected Lie subgroups $G_1$ and $G_2$ of $G$ such that the Lie algebra corresponding to $G_1$ (resp. $G_2$) is $\mathfrak g_1$ (resp. $\mathfrak g_2$). This observation is based on the following result by Lee (see Introduction to smooth manifolds, theorem 20.21)

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $\mathfrak g$ its associated Lie algebra. Assume that $\mathfrak h$ is a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak g$. Then there exists a unique connected Lie subgroup $H$ of $G$ whose associated Lie algebra is $\mathfrak h$.

I would like to show that $G = G_1 \times G_2$. Because $G_1\times G_2$ and $G$ have the same Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$, and that both of these Lie groups are connected, I know that it suffices to show that $G_1\times G_2\leq G$. In this case, I could argue that as $G$ and $G_1\times G_2$ are both connected Lie subgroups of $G$ with the same Lie algebra, that by the Theorem quoted above, $G = G_1\times G_2$.
However, although I can show that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are normal subgroups of $G$, I am struggling with showing that $G_1 \cap G_2$ is trivial. I know that the Lie algebra associated to $G_1 \cap G_2$ is $\mathfrak g_1\cap \mathfrak g_2$, which is trivial.
However, because I don't know if $G_1\cap G_2$ is connected, I don't know if this implies that $G_1 \cap G_2 = \{1\}.$
Does anyone know how to overcome this problem, or how to prove that $\mathfrak g$ being decomposable implies that $G$ is decomposable.
Thanks in advance!

$G_1,G_2$ might fail to be closed. For instance, take $G$ to be a 2-dim torus and 2 irrational lines.

Do you mean that $G_1\cap G_2$ might fail to be closed?

It certainly isn't true that $\mathfrak{g}$ being decomposable implies that $G$ is. Simply take the example of $SO(4)$ whose Lie algebra splits as $\mathfrak{so}(4) = \mathfrak{so}(3)\oplus\mathfrak{so}(3)$ but the corresponding Lie subgroups, which are the left and right isoclinic rotation groups respectively, intersect at $I$ and $-I$.
Over semisimple groups like this, the result that we have is that the corresponding simply connected group decomposes into a direct product (as will the adjoint group). I'm not sure if we can say this for non-semisimple groups as well.

Thanks for your answer! I am working with connected and simply connected Lie groups (and in fact linear algebraic groups). Do these extra conditions help?
